# How to transition from the start position in a loop?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have a dot in d3 that is kept under the transition method. When simulate is pressed, it goes to a certain position and returns from that position to the original position. It's under continuous loop so all it does is it goes and comes in the same position.

What I want to do is make it work continuously like it is working now but when it moves from A to B, it should not come back from B to A, it should again start from A to B. Basically A to B, A to B continuously. Here is the code that I'm working with.

```
dot.transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .attr("cx", 500)
        .attr("cy", 80).on("start", function repeat() {
            d3.active(this)
                .attr("cx", 70)
                .attr("cy", 350)
              .transition()
                .attr("cx", 500)
                .attr("cy", 80) 
              .transition()
                .on("start", repeat);
          });
```

Can you please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple refactor, using `on.("end")` instead of `.on("start")`:

```js
const dot = d3.select("circle");

dot.transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .attr("cx", 250)
  .attr("cy", 100).on("end", function repeat() {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", 50)
      .attr("cy", 50)
      .transition()
      .duration(3000)
      .attr("cx", 250)
      .attr("cy", 100)
      .on("end", repeat)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="10" cx="50" cy="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

But I reckon that this would be more elegant and clear if you used `selection.call` (which you could use with different and arguments):

```js
const dot = d3.select("circle");

dot.call(transition)

function transition(element) {
  element.attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("cx", 250)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .on("end", function() {
      transition(element)
    })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="10" cx="50" cy="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

By the way, since D3 transitions use d3.easeCubic as the default as the default easing, you can get a better effect (depending on what you want) if you use a linear easing:

```js
const dot = d3.select("circle");

dot.call(transition)

function transition(element) {
  element.attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("cx", 250)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .on("end", function() {
      transition(element)
    })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="10" cx="50" cy="50"></circle>
</svg>
```